# displaying in android a timed custom dialog while pausing main thread execution

Tags: android, multithreading, sleep, timertask, customdialog

I am showing a custom dialog in my application, which stays for a small time, (say 2 seconds) and then disappears. I am calling this custom dialog from the main activity.
 I want my calling activity to be paused till the custom dialog disappears. The issue is that activity code **after** the dialog is dismissed is always executed, while the dialog is being shown.

I have tried showing the dialog, sleeping for 2 seconds and then dismiss it, which is not working. The activity code after the dialog is dismissed is executing.

```
cust_dlg.show();
Thread.sleep(2000);
cust_dlg.dismiss();
```

I have also tried putting the dialog in a timer task, which also fails

```
        final Timer t = new Timer();
        cust_dlg.show();
        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
        cust_dlg.dismiss();
        t.cancel();
        }
        }, 500);
```

I have also tried simple threading with the custom dialog in a thread and put sleep simultaneously in the main activity, which causes exception and force closes.

Somebody please tell me a way to pause the main activity while the custom dialog is shown, so that the code after the custom dialog dismiss is **NOT** executed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a Handler

```
        Handler handler = new Handler(); 
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
             public void run() { 


        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RBLQuizSpiel.this);
        if (aktuellGeloest == true){

        builder.setMessage(R.string.quiz_neu)
                .setTitle(R.string.quiz_glueckwunsch)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.quiz_ja, dialogClickListener)
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.quiz_nein, dialogClickListener).show();
        } else {
            builder.setMessage(R.string.quiz_neu)
            .setTitle(R.string.quiz_schade)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.quiz_ja, dialogClickListener)
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.quiz_nein, dialogClickListener).show();

        }
        }
}, 1500);
```

no more code behind this.

1500 = ms

Well an you need to set the execution of the following code in the Clicklistner.
Android is event-driven OS. The Dialog will be put in a message qeue and your program steps on..

Comment: Thanks for the response, killphil75, but this doesnt solve the problem, since by the time the click is listened, the code later would have been executed. Also I dont want to make the custom dialog as clickable in the first place.